# What happens if I install an AI in a prisoner's brain?

Tags: rimworld

The operations menu gives me an option to install a AI persona core into the brain of one of my prisoners. What are the effects of me doing this?

(I'm using the EPOE mod.)

[image: Ai Persona core]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's not too many adverse effects you wouldn't expect. The prisoner would gain the abilities/penalties of the AI and they would continue living their life. If you send them back, they might return and if they do, they could still have your AI installed. Not sure if this is what you were looking for but you wouldn't get his brain and if you wanted to see the AI's stats, you can inspect it to see its effectiveness in different stats.

One way you can exploit raiders returning is by administering luciferium, sending them back and they'll return with their own stash of luciferium.

Comment: That's just evil, I like it.

Comment: Just how the game works man, survival of the craftiest and the eviliest.